# Auto focus on input when opening chrome dev tools console tab

Tags: macos, google-chrome-devtools

I hope I'm not the only one who would benefit if there's a way to auto focus on input field whenever I open `Console` tab of chrome dev tools.

I'm on Mac and don't mind use any external tools if that helps.

[image]

Comment: It's probably a bug because the input is focused automatically here in Windows.

Comment: Reported a bug, feel free to add in more context in the bug report https://issues.chromium.org/issues/328662560

Comment: @Jecfish can't access that link 'Access is denied to this issue'